# How to make $@ start one iteration ahead

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm running a bash script and am reading file contents of each one, but I want to skip the first one. I know of the "shift" command, but I'm having trouble getting it to go one over. I currently have $@ in a while loop.

Comment: Please edit your post to show what you have already done in your script.

Comment: `shift` should be correct. Show the relevant code you have now.

Comment: As written, your question is not going to be useful to anyone. At least include enough context to understand why `shift` wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "subscript" that pseudo-array. It starts with $1, so to iterate over $2, $3, ...

```
for arg in "${@:2}"; do 
    echo "$arg"
done
```

Comment: I ended up finding another way but your way looks like it'd work too.